# Analytic functions with uncountable zeros

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose for an analytic function $f$ its zero set $Z_f$ is uncountable. Show that $f ≡ 0$.
Can we show that the set has a limit point? Hence the result.

Comment: This is false without further hypotheses. Start by telling us what the domain of $f$ is.

Answer (score 5):

The complex plane is the union of countably many compact sets, and some of the compact sets must contain infinitely many zeros.

Answer (score 1):

Yes every uncountable set has a limit point. More than that it has a condensation point.

Comment: I guess jaggu u dont have any of your own ideas. As we can see from your questions..please try a bit more than that i guess you're a nbhm aspirant and csir aspirant....

Comment: Can you help me in doing that?

Comment: The help,if any has to come from your end only..just try to give your thoughts on the questions maybe wrong but still..

Answer (score 1):

The zeros of an analytic function that is not the zero function are isolated.

This means that for each zero there is a disk that contains it and no other zero. In each such disk there is a point with rational coordinates. The rational point for each disk is different because the disks are disjoint.

This gives an injection from the set of zeros into $\mathbb Q \times \mathbb Q$, which is countable. Therefore, the set of zeros is countable.