# Why is this set finite or empty?

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a question regarding an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2447105/465015) given in an older post:

The original question was:

> Let $f$ be an entire function. Let $Z(f)$ be the set of all zeros of $f$ which is further uncountable. We have to show that $Z(f)$ has a limit point in $\mathbb{C}$.

And the answer was given as:

> Let $K_n:=\{z∈\mathbb{C}:|z|≤n\}$ for $n∈\mathbb{N}$ and suppose that $Z(f)$ has no limit point in $\mathbb{C}$. Since $f$ is continuous and $K_n$ is compact, $Z(f)∩K_n$ must be finite or empty. But then
>   $$Z(f)= \bigcup _{n=1}^{\infty}Z(f) \cap K_n$$
>   is at most countable.

Why is it that if $f$ is continuous and $K_n$ is compact, then $Z(f)∩K_n$ must be finite or empty?

And why is $Z(f)= \bigcup _{n=1}^{\infty}Z(f) \cap K_n$ at most countable?

Comment: This is sequential compactness: any sequence in a compact set has a convergent subsequence, and hence every infinite subset of a compact set has a limit point.  It follows that any subset of a compact set with no limit point is finite.

Comment: Note that the question really doesn't have anything to do with complex analysis.  It proves that any uncountable set of points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ must have a limit point.

Comment: I don't know why the answer mentions continuity of $f$ as that is not relevant.  (note the above argument only works for subsets of a metric space. In general compactness != sequential compactness.)